# Is it "In New Delhi" or "at New Delhi"?

Tags: prepositions

My Home India will organise "Nest Fest - 2018" on Saturday **at New Delhi** to create awareness and celebrate the cultural diversity of the Northeast region, where Chief Minister Biplab Kumar Deb along with other Northeast leaders will also take part in the festival at Talkatora Stadium in New Delhi.

Answer (score 1):

*In New Delhi*, if you mean the city. The only time you could use *at* would be if you were referring not to the city but to an event in the city. For example, suppose there is a range of festivals in different cities, you could say *at New Delhi* meaning "at the festival in New Delhi".

Comment: It's usual to use 'in' with a big city, 'at' with a smaller place.

Comment: I was brought up in a wee village in SE England called Wallcrouch (too small for me to find the population on the internet). I have done a Google search for "in Wallcrouch" and "at Wallcrouch" (with the quote marks) and got  521 hits for the first and 112 for the second, most of  the latter being references to Wallcrouch Farm (or something else where Wallcrouch was a qualifier), or referring to a road junction (which clearly needs "at"), or giving the location of something else (e.g. "the barn at Wallcrouch") or of a photograph. So "in" is the generally preferred option in this example.

Comment: When I used to take piano exams as a child, I noticed that the biographical notes about the composer in the books of pieces used this convention. "W.A. Mozart, born at Salzburg 1756, died in Vienna 1791".